# REST API call not working

Tags: javascript, rest, api, object

I have tried to use both .ajax and .getJSON, but neither methods have worked.  I am using the goodzer rest api.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#click" ).click(function() {
  $.ajax({url: "https://api.goodzer.com/products/v0.1/search_stores/?query=v-neck+sweater&lat=40.714353&lng=-74.005973&radius=5&priceRange=30:120&apiKey=APIKEY", success: function(result){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                }});
        });
    });
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.goodzer.com/products/v0.1/search_stores/?query=v-neck+sweater&lat=40.714353&lng=-74.005973&radius=5&priceRange=30:120&apiKey=APIKEY',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function() { alert('get completed'); }
});
```

Comment: You should remove that key ASAP. This site is indexed by google and someone will quite likely abuse your key.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you checked the JavaScript console on your browser?

Comment: Perhaps you can add modify output that you are receiving in response.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to switch the code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#click" ).click(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.goodzer.com/products/v0.1/search_stores/?query=v-neck+sweater&lat=40.714353&lng=-74.005973&radius=5&priceRange=30:120&apiKey=API-KEY", function(result){
        alert(result.stores_found);
                });
        });
    });
```

And codePen for some reason did not allow this code to run.

Comment: Cool, I think the problem was in your earlier code you were getting the response as HTML. 
When you use getJSON , it sends this header Accept: application/json which basically tells the server that client expects response in json.